# List of list to data frame when inner list contains a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of 2 rows. Each element in the list is also a list:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$column1
[1] "0"

[[1]]$column2
[1] "0" "1"

[[2]]
[[2]]$column1
[1] "1"

[[2]]$column2
[1] "0" "2" "3" "3"
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe like this:

```
    column1     column2
1   0           "0" "1"
2   1           "0" "2" "3" "3"
```

I tried using

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(my_list), nrow=2, byrow=T), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

but it does not understand the fact that the values of a column may be a vector.

Can a cell in a dataframe hold vectors? If so, how do I convert this to get it in the required format?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option, use `list.rbind` from `rlist`

```
library(rlist)
as.data.frame(list.rbind(lst))
#  column1    column2
#1       0       0, 1
#2       1 0, 2, 3, 3
```

---

Without additional package

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, rbind)))
```

**data**

```
lst <- list(structure(list(column1 = "0", column2 = c("0", "1")), .Names = c("column1", 
"column2")), structure(list(column1 = "1", column2 = c("0", "2", 
"3", "3")), .Names = c("column1", "column2")))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a follow up, my `column1` will always be a single value. How can I sort the rows based on `column1`? 
I get the error `unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'`

Comment: Try `DF[order(as.numeric(DF$column1)), ]`, where `DF` is the data.frame created above.